# Efficient and practical way to pass a function as a parameter, when the function may have a variable number of arguments in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I would like to build a class that operates on a given mathematical function. The given mathematical function could be simple or very complex, but will always have:

- one independent variable
- one result for that variable
- **an unknown and potentially large number of constants**

For the sake of argument, let's say I just want to print the result of these functions, in reality the operations would be complex (e.g. iterating to find a root).

I am not sure of a better way to accomplish this other than adding the variable number of arguments to a dictionary, such that I can always pass a given function as a delegate.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub RunTest()
    Dim myvars As New Dictionary(Of String, Double) From {
        {"a", 3},
        {"b", 2},
        {"c", 1},
        {"d", -1}
    }

    Dim MyTest1, MyTest2 As MyTestClass

    MyTest1 = New MyTestClass(AddressOf CubicTest, 1.123, myvars)
    MyTest2 = New MyTestClass(AddressOf QuadTest, 1.123, myvars)
    MyTest1.TestPrint()
    MyTest2.TestPrint()
End Sub

Function CubicTest(ByVal xAs Double, ByVal var As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double
    Return var("a") * x^ 3 + var("b") * x^ 2 + var("c") * x + var("d")
End Function

Function QuadTest(ByVal xAs Double, ByVal var As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double
    Return var("b") * x^ 2 + var("c") * x + var("d")
End Function

Class MyTestClass
    Private BaseFunction As FunctionByRef
    Private TestValue As Double
    Private Variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double)

    Delegate Function FunctionByRef(ByVal TestValue As Double, ByVal Variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double

    Sub New(ByVal BaseFunction As FunctionByRef, ByVal TestValue As Double, ByVal Variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double))
        Me.BaseFunction = BaseFunction
        Me.TestValue = TestValue
        Me.Variables = Variables
    End Sub

    Sub TestPrint()
        Debug.Print(Me.BaseFunction(Me.TestValue, Me.Variables).ToString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Which seems to work just fine, but also seems very clunky.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As a general example:

```
Private Sub ExecuteDoubleFunction(method As [Delegate], ParamArray args As Object())
    Dim result = DirectCast(method.DynamicInvoke(args), Double)

    'Use result here.
End Sub
```

You can then pass any delegate with a return type of `Double` to that method and you can pass the arguments as a single array or as discrete values. That means that you can use `AddressOf` to create a delegate for a conventional method of use a Lambda expression.